# POSTGRESQL: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 36: invalid start byte

Tags: pgadmin-4

I just downloaded and installed PostgreSQL from here

https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

I wanted to create my first server but I get this error

> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 36: invalid start byte

[image: error]

My pg service is running automatically

[image: service]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Same thing here (postgresql 9.6 on windows) when I tried to using query tool. 
It's happend after I changed postgres user password using pgadmin 4. 
I simply restarted the postgresql service, started pgadmin 4 and then it asked for the new password. After typed it, no more error message.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed PGADMIN version 4.11 in windows 10 and the issue persists...

So I shut down the PGADMIN instance in the task-tray and started it again from the start menu.

Typed the 'master password' and voila, it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following line at the end of the data\pg_hba.conf file and then restart the PostgreSQL service.

```
host    all             all             all                 md5
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with pgAdmin4 v3.0.

Could you try downloading the latest version of pgAdmin4 & Check?
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: i'm having the same issue, with pgAdmin4 v3.0 - psql is on a windows server in french and my pgadmin on a windows 10 in french too

Comment: Please report the bug.

Comment: I am using version 4.8 but still getting the same error.